# Trying to convert a .npy file (float64) to uint8 or uint16

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vtk

I'm trying to display a 3D Numpy Array using VTK (python 3) but it needs the type to be uint8 or uint16.

I don't know how to do this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

In case, there's nothing I can do, I just want to display my .npy file using VTK. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the numpy.astype() function to change the data type.  Here's an example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([10., 20., 30., 40., 50.]) 
>>> print(arr)
[10. 20. 30. 40. 50.]
>>> print(arr.dtype)
float64
>>> arr = arr.astype('uint16')
>>> print(arr)
[10 20 30 40 50]
>>> print(arr.dtype)
uint16
```

To address your further questions, you want to normalize your data when converting float64 to uint8 or uint16.  Basically you want to map the [min, max] data range of your array to [0, 255] for uint8 or [0, 65535] for uint16.  You'll still lose information, but normalization minimizes the data loss.

Here's how you'd map float64 to uint8:

```
dmin = np.min(arr)
dmax = np.max(arr)
drange = dmax-dmin
dscale = 255.0/drange
new_arr = (arr-dmin)*dscale
new_arr_uint8 = new_arr.astype('uint8')
```

And, yes, the astype function will work on a loaded array.

Comment: Would that convert floats like 0.00000134 to integers though?

Comment: That would get converted to 0.

Comment: But that won't give me a very accurate image, would it?

Comment: It depends on your data.  When converting to byte or short types, people will usually re-scale their data to minimize the loss of information.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to this whole thing. How can I do that?

Comment: I must mention, I'm using the np.load("file") function for a .npy file. Will the .astype() still work?